Table data don't align when using multiple components in Angular
I'm experimenting with and learning Angular. Why doesn't the table data align with the table columns in this example? I'm using Angular 15.
I expected the component tags to not appear in the DOM, but when I inspect the document there they are.

In HTML, the table follows a strict structure.
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody childComponent>
    <tr>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td>Data2</td>
      <td>Data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data4</td>
      <td>Data5</td>
      <td>Data6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

When you use a component to render the content inside the TR, it causes the Table to be misalgined due to the extra component tag app-child-component inbetween the body tag and the inner contents.
To solve this you need to create a component without inserting an additional tag inside the parent. For this we will use the other selectors of angular.
[childComponent] -> attribute selector - which is the attributes of the HTML element (shown in above HTML) (solution for your scenario)
.child-component -> class selector - can use a class to create a component
app-child-component -> element selector -> will create an HTML element in the output html (problem in your scenario)
So we can change the selector to be,
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[childComponent]',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponentComponent {

}

And in the parent HTML we can set it to.
<tbody childComponent>
</tbody>

Github Repo Fork

Thank you so much for the reply, really helpful.
